# Can't delete file in deployment tab

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

As the title says, after entering a file and location in the deployment tab for an iOS/Android FMX project, afterwards I can not go back and delete the file. The IDE has the delete button on the toolbar for the deployment tab greyed out ( it is greyed out for everything ) and even when I uncheck a certain deployment file, e.g., one of the ones I added manually, they still get deployed.

Am I doing anything wrong, or is this a bug that there is a work around for?

Comment: Try editing the .dproj file

Comment: That along with simply renaming the files worked too, of course. Is the greyed out delete button a bug?

Comment: Possibly. I'm not familiar with that part of the product.

Comment: The deployment tab could really benefit from some polish. It still behaves like a beta product, but after some time you find out how to tweak it :-)

Comment: ^ apparently. How do you go about deleting though?

Comment: Edit the dproj file and move on.

Answer (score 1):

The only deployment files that you can delete inside the IDE are those with Type=File
The rest serves a purpose on the OS and not even removing them from `.dproj` and `.deployproj` works as Delphi seem to recreate them in an attempt to be fool proof.

However, the only file that I have had a need to replace is the `info.plist` file and so far I managed to make that work. I simply added my own info.plist file for deployment, then unchecked the default plist on the deployment tab and finally run the application.

Next time I open my project the default plist is checked again, but, at least for me, my own info.plist is deployed **after** the default one, so it overwrites it every time and therefore still works. Sometimes it forgets the order of the .plist deployment and deploys the default one as the last one. Then I just uncheck it again, and it works again.

This is a really hacky approach, but the only way I found to work around it. At least it works for me.